# c# - multicast packets not being sent when offline

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming

Good day all

I am testing this code for offline LAN use, but multicast packets are not sent if the sender is offline (my conclusion which I am in doubt of).

For purposes of discovering packet, I use

> Wireshark

with a

> "QUIC" protocol filter

**Problem:**

When I am online (does not matter which connection, as long as I have internet access), my multicast packets get sent,

but, the moment I disconnect from the internet, no packet is sent, then when I connect to the internet, packets are sent.

Thus,

- internet connection -> packets are sent,
- no internet connection -> no packets sent

**UPDATED**

*p.s. - this code should send a multicast packet(s) over all interfaces*

```
IPAddress_MultiIP = IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.3");
```

and

```
   Socket _listener_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            foreach (IPAddress localIP in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Where(i => i.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
            {
                //handle image and files                
                _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(_MultiIP/*, localIP*/));
                _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 1);
                _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                _listener_socket.MulticastLoopback = true;
                _listener_socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(_MultiIP, _PORT));
                //send data to multicast group
                string message_to_send = _IPADDRESS.ToString() + "~m~" + _MESSAGE + "\n";
                byte[] bytes = new byte[message_to_send.Length * sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(message_to_send.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                _listener_socket.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            _listener_socket.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth, a system restart seemed to resolve this problem???

I have no idea what caused this in the first place.

If you have this problem, try adapter(s) reset, else restart and report back.

Hope this helps